# Some users report error when buying In App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a very tricky issue with my iOS-app. For some reason very few users have reported an error when upgrading to premium version, the payment goes through, but the app never gets updated to premium. In my estimate between 1-3% of users have had this issue. I have not been able to re-create the error these users are experiencing with my own devices. Which makes it really hard to figure out exactly what is causing it.

But the users have reported that when they try try re-buy premium, they get the message from App Store that the item has already been bought and it will be restored. But then again, it never gets restored. Also the same issue when trying to restore previous purchases.

I will provide the code I figure is interesting, and hopefully someone may know what is causing this behavior in just a few of my users. Keep in mind that the error is not when purchasing or restoring. But when the product has been purchased or restored, that is when the app just doesn't get updated. (See "Comment 1" and "Comment 2" in code).

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch(transaction.transactionState){
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");

            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            //Purchase finished
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");

            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.Premium"]) {
                //Comment 1: Method under never gets called in users with error
                [self upgradeToPremium];
            } else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.250Coins"]) {
                [self addCoins:250];
            } else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.600Coins"]) {
                [self addCoins:600];
            } else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.1500Coins"]) {
                [self addCoins:1500];
            } else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.4500Coins"]) {
                [self addCoins:4500];
            } else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.10000Coins"]) {
                [self addCoins:10000];
            } else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.25000Coins"]) {
                [self addCoins:25000];
            }

            //Comment 2: Method under never gets called in users with error
            [self finishPurchase];

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];


            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            //Purchase restored
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.yyy.Premium"]) {
                [self upgradeToPremium];
            }


            [self finishPurchase];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            //called when the transaction does not finish

            if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                //the user cancelled the payment ;(
            }

            [self finishPurchase];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Defferred");

            [self finishPurchase];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;
    }
}
}


- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

int count = (int)queue.transactions.count;

if(count > 0) {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions){
        if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
            //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

            [self upgradeToPremium];
            [self finishPurchase];

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    [self finishPurchase];
}
}

- (void)upgradeToPremium {
    NSLog(@"PREMIUM");

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PREMIUM"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

EDIT: Another option would be to implement a way for users experiencing this error to unlock premium. Some kind of workaround. I have been thinking of something like promo codes to unlock premium. Anyone has an idea of how to implement something like that?

Comment: When you say "it never gets restored" - are you triggering the restore yourself? This isn't done automatically and you need to [restoreCompletedTransactions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions?language=objc) yourself.

Comment: @enc_life I updated the question with the restoreCompletedTransaction method I use

Comment: Your code in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactions` is incorrect. That function is just used to update the UI or perform any other housekeeping once restoration is complete. You don't process transactions. What do `upgradeToPremium` and `finishPurchase` do? Can they fail?

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, but that should not make it fail like this. I updated the question with the upgradeToPremium(). I can assure you that it can not fail, and neither can finishPurchase. All finishPurchase does is to deactivate the purchase process, which includes turning off the UIActivityIndicatorView, and I know for sure this does not happen with users experiencing the error.

Comment: You don't need the `synchronize` call.  You're right; I can't see how it can fail.  You don't seem to notify existing view controllers that that the "unlock" has occurred, but maybe that doesn't matter; I don't know how the rest of your app is structured. At the very least, it should be picked up next time your app loads. If you use codes or any other mechanism you will fail App Store review.  I can't see any other issues with the code you have shown, so either people are lying or there is a problem where you actually unlock the premium features.

Comment: How do you know that `finishPurchase` *never gets called in users with error*?   If that method just updates the UI, why do you call it for each transaction? Shouldn't you call it once, at the end of the `for` loop?